# gtkmm glib gio critical

Tags: c++, gtk, glib, gtkmm

On running the following simple.cc example for gtkmm

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app
    = Gtk::Application::create(argc,argv,"org.gtkmm..examples.base");
  Gtk::Window window;
  //Gtk::ApplicationWindow window(app);                                         
  return app->run(window);                                                  
}
```

I face the following message:

```
 (process:9428): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_application_set_application_id: assertion `application_id == NULL || g_application_id_is_valid (application_id)' failed
```

However, the application doesn't break, the window is produced and doesn't exit until I ctr+C the program.

What are the implications of this GLib-GIO-Critical message ? What do I do to suppress the message ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the provided application-id is not valid then it will not be set.  I'm not familiar with the glibmm bits, but if you don't provide an ID to [g_application_new](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-new) then, according to the documentation, "...some features of GApplication (most notably application uniqueness) will be disabled."

"Suppressing" it is easy--just fix it.  Provide a valid application ID or don't provide one at all (pass NULL instead of a string).  In your example, getting rid of the extra dot ("org.gtkmm.examples.base" instead of "org.gtkmm..examples.base") should do the trick.  The [g_application_id_is_valid](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplication.html#g-application-id-is-valid) documentation explains what constitutes a valid ID, including that "Application identifiers must not contain consecutive '.' (period) characters."

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad with the explanation in the solution but .. based on that just pass an empty string "". However "org.gtkmm.example" should work